# Get second CSS selector selenium vba

Tags: html, css

I am trying to inspect an element and I have used css selector
Here's the HTML

```html
<div class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation0 jss325 MuiPaper-rounded">
  <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation1 jss329 MuiPaper-rounded" style="text-align: right;">
    <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container">
      <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-2" style="margin-top: 14px; padding-right: 10px;"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" style="cursor: pointer;"><path d="M12 2C8.13 2 5 5.13 5 9c0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z"></path></svg></div>
      <div
        class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-9" style="margin-top: 10px;"><span class="MuiTypography-root jss330 MuiTypography-body1">الرقم الآلي للوحدة 10670235</span><br><span class="MuiTypography-root jss331 MuiTypography-body1">العديلية - قطعة 3 - شارع عيسى عبد الرحمن العسعوسي - قسيمة 129 - منزل 19 - الدور الأرضي - الرقم الآلي للوحدة 10670235</span></div>
  </div>
  <hr class="MuiDivider-root" style="margin-right: 30px; margin-left: 30px;">
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following css selector `span.MuiTypography-root` but I found multiple instances. How can I get the desired one only?
The desired text is after the element `MuiTypography-root jss331 MuiTypography-body1`

I can't use this `jss331`  as this is created dynamically

Comment: can you try using sudo selector ```nth-child```

Comment: Are you trying to get both spans or just one of them? If so which one? They both have the exact same classes so 2 results would be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more specifiers by just chaining:

```
span.MuiTypography-root.jss331
```

This will get any `span` with classes `MuiTypography-root` and `jss331`.
You can chain more as needed.

**PS:** you can test out selectors by hitting `ctrl + f` while inspecting the elements. You can type in text to find, CSS selectors, and XPath if I remember correctly

**Edit:** if a class is dynamic then we have to go by what we know is consistent. If we can assume it will always be the last-child then you can use `span.MuiTypography-root:last-child`

Or if it's always the third child then `span.MuiTypography-root:nth-child(3)`

Or (if it's always the second `span` with the `MuiTypography-root` class) in whatever app you're using selenium, you can use the `find_elements_by_css_selector` method, which returns an array, and access the second element found.

Comment: @YasserKhalil why did you not mention that in your question? Seems like important and relevant information

Comment: @YasserKhalil I've edited my answer. Hopefully it helps

Answer (score -1):

So you want to inspect this one `MuiTypography-root jss331 MuiTypography-body1`

Did you tried this:-

```
     span.MuiTypography-root:last-child{
        border: 1px solid;
        background-color: gold;
    }
```

Comment: yes, using querySelector will return the first match. which in this case is the element with class `jss330`. he needs `js331`! look up your print-screen one more time. And because the question has not any javascript tag, I guess javascript is not an option here.

Comment: I've fixed my mistake. --spider parker--